# Where can I find official iOS Layout Margin documentation?

Tags: ios, layout, autolayout

Just getting back into iOS Development after a 4 year break. The documentation seems to have taken a massive turn for the worse with their attempts to modernise and deprecate.

All I’m looking for is the official explanation on how to use layout margins and edge insets, but I can’t find a guide for it anywhere. It’s not mentioned in the Autolayout Guide. Can someone please point me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Here you can find View Layout info form UIKit framework Apple documentation https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/view_layout

Comment: Maybe this one helps https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/positioning_content_within_layout_margins?language=objc